# Java/Android class data member not retaining value after listener

Tags: java, android, scope, listener

I have a class called RandoMessenger. The class has a string data member called message. I have an EditText component. The component has a listener to indicate when the user pressed enter. Upon this action the variable message is set to the text the user typed in. Later on in the program (outside the listener) I have an if statement that checks to see if message is not null. If this validates then the message is passed to a server. This if statement never validates unless I set messenger to something upon declaration. Relevant comments are in all caps in code below.

I am testing on Andy emulator 4.4.2 and Samsung Galaxy S3 4.4.2

```
package com.Rando;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class RandoMessenger extends ActionBarActivity {

public PrintWriter out;
public BufferedReader in;

//THE IF STATEMENT VALIDATES IF I SET MESSAGE TO SOMETHING HERE. IT DOES NOT VALIDATE 
// IF MESSAGE IS SET IN THE LISTENER BELOW
public String message="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rando_messenger);


    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
            final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            edit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                   //MESSAGE IS INITIALIZED HERE INSIDE THE LISTENER BUT THE IF STATEMENT 
                   //BELOW NEVER VALIDATES INDICATING MESSAGE IS "" OUTSIDE THE LISTENER
                        message=edit.getText().toString();
                        edit1.append("\n");
                        edit1.append("Listener Works");
                        edit.setText("");

                      return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


                //Edited out the actual IP
                String serverAddress = "00.000.00.000";
                Socket socket;


                try {

                    socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);

                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


                while (true) {
                    String line = in.readLine();

                    //THIS IF STATEMENT DOES NOT VALIDATE WHEN MESSAGE IS SET
                    //INSIDE THE LISTENER ABOVE
                    if(message != "")
                    {

                        out.println("Test");
                        edit1.setText(message);
                        message="";
                    }

                    if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                        out.println("User");
                    } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                      edit1.append("Connection Successful");
                    } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                        //Append message to output field here
                        edit1.append("\n");
                        edit1.append(line);
                    }   
                }
            }
                   catch(IOException e)
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
        }.start();

    //Temporary dialog for server IP input
    /*******************************************************************/
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Server");
    alert.setMessage("Enter the server IP address:");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    Editable value = input.getText();
    //edit1.append(value);
    }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
    }   
    });

    alert.show();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rando_messenger, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main mistake is using `message != ""` to compare the message. In Java, string comparisons should be done using `!string1.equals(string2)` or in this case `!message.equals("")`.